Maven compilation failure (package does not exist) with external jar
I'm trying to wrap my head around how Maven works but I never had any formation and it seems all my guesses end up wrong, so here I am.
I'm using Eclipse. I have 2 projects A and B.
A references B as a "Required project". I can build A.jar fine using Maven with Goals: "package". In project B, I then add A.jar as a Referenced library, not in the pom !
Eclipse shows no errors. However, when I try to Maven: "package" project B, I get a compilation failure saying package xxx (which is a part of A) does not exist. Of course, it does. It is present in A.jar, which is referrenced in B.
I don't need classes from A to be included in B.jar. I just need it to compile. I don't understand where Maven goes to fetch these packages. Where could it be, apart inside the referenced library? Where does Maven look for Referenced libraries classes?
Of couse, my coworker who uses the same setup gets it to work just fine. But all the config I checked (pom, build path classpath) is the same as me. I tried to do an Eclipse Project Clean, Maven clean, Maven update, to no avail so far.
EDIT : I can make it work by using Maven "install" on project A, then adding a dependency to A in project B's pom, so I'm not interested in a "solution", per se. I want to better understand how Maven works, specifically in the case of a Referenced dependency.

Can you share a [mcve]?

@Mureinik unfortunately I can't, this is proprietary code I don't have the right to share.

Why not adding it as a dependency in POM ?That's the way Maven works?

I know. I'm not the one who decided. Regardless, it's working for my coworker, I would like to understand why it's not working for me.

Possibly duplicate of "Maven: best way of linking custom external JAR to my project?". The same scenario (B needs A) and various solutions discussed and explained.

tl;dr: The problem is that whatever you configure in the Eclipse UI (referencing some other eclipse project) has absolutely no effect on how maven resolves dependencies. mvn install of A however does create a local artifact that can be used as dependency.
Now for the longer version...
How maven actually resolves dependencies
For every dependency declared in a project's pom.xml, Maven will attempt to find a matching artifact (aka a jar file). This algorithm is (simplified) two staged:

First search the local repo. On your computer you will find a hidden folder in your home directory, named .m2. If there's a match for the dependency in question, maven will happily stop here and build the project.
If there was no match in the local repository, search for a match in the official online repository. If found, cache it in the local repo and build. If also no match in the official repo... Fail.

Why does mvn install of A fix the issue ?
What you describe perfectly makes sense.

Out of the box, you cannot build B, because maven has no clue how the dependency to A can be resolved. The above algorithm neither finds A in the local repo, nor in the official one (because it's not an official library)
However, you can build A, because this project has no unresolvable depdencies. Now here is the important part:

mvn package in A: just builds A
mvn install in A: builds A and places a copy of the jar in your local .m2 repo.


Once you installed A, you can build B, as you observed. The algorithm described above finds an artifact for A in the local .m2 repo and all goes well.


Check your co-worker's local repo (.m2 repo). My bet is that they ran mvn install and therefore have A.jar inside... which then is correctly picked up my maven's algorithm.

Addendum:

Eclipse clean has no effect, because maven does not care about what you configure in eclipse.
mvn clean has no effect, because it has nothing to do with dependency management. mvn clean just deletes the target folder, i.e. the folder where maven produces the "built" software.
mvn update has no effect, because this is a command to refresh the log / database.


As I said, it's working when I add the project as a Maven dependency like you suggest. I want to understand what makes the whole situation work on my coworker's desk, and fail on mine.

The most plausible explanation is that they satisfy the dependency to A with an artifact in their local .m2 repo and added a dependency in Bs pom.xml. The idea of build systems is to have a reliable build via configuration files rather than IDE click-based menues, so building can be automatized. The only other option I can think of is that your co-worker has an eclipse plugin installed that interferes with maven's dependency resolving. Possibly check their list of installed plugins.
